# Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and I am getting an error "dalvikvm(11625): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)" when I try to run my application on certain devices. Please help me to rectify the error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may have lots of objects allocated in jni but not released

or, NewGlobalRef no corresponding DeleteGlobalRef

Comment: Can you please explain. I am having an assets folder with so many png files and a sqllight database in it.Is this the reason ?

Comment: It is irrelevant to your asset files. Try read your source code to find those places you allocate a new jni object. Then see if you have corresponding release on the object. If you can share part of the source code, it will be more helpful